# Parsing XML document in java using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

Here is an xml document I want to parse. I need to get all of the balances of the accounts and add them together to get a total. But I am at a loss for how to do this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!-- <!DOCTYPE bank SYSTEM "bank.dtd"> -->

-<bank>
   -<account>
        <number>3</number>
        <balance>1295.32</balance>
   </account>
  -<account>
        <number>5</number>
        <balance>3504.63</balance>
   </account>
  -<account>
        <number>7</number>
        <balance>872.00</balance>
    </account>
</bank>
```

I have this code so far but cannot get it to work and don't know how to go about this.

```
public Bank parse(String fileName) throws SAXException, IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Document doc = builder.parse(f);

    // get the bank

    Bank b = new Bank();

    XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath path = xpfactory.newXPath();



       int itemCount =    Integer.parseInt(path.evaluate("count(/bank/account/number)",
            doc));


    for (int i = 1; i<= itemCount; i++) {

String balance = path.compile
   ("/bank/account[" + i +  "]/number/balance").evaluate(doc);

   System.out.println(balance);
```

Comment: Your Java code is incomplete (please post at least the full method). Are you printing the balance for each account? You can also sum all balances with one XPath expression: `sum(/bank/account/balance)`.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath where you read the item count is correct.

You can get the sum of all the balance elements with:

```
sum(/bank/account/balance)
```

There is no `/bank/account[1]/number/balance`. That expression returns an empty result set. If you want the individual balance, replace `/number/balance/` for simply `/balance`:

```
String balance = path.compile("/bank/account[" + i + "]/balance").evaluate(doc);
```